# How is the short term frequency stability of a crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

I have a circuit board with two identical crystal oscillators. Can I assume that one is always faster than the other?

Say that I count the number of oscillations from each and reset the counters every second. Will one counter always show a higher value than the other, or will it typically vary from second to second which counter shows the higher value?

The oscillator accuracy is obviously limited by the PPM value in the datasheet, the question is whether this PPM value is constant over short times given constant age, temperature, etc.

Comment: It is as specified in the datasheet

Comment: I would compare your question to: "If I continuously lean a bit to the safe side, it is fine to walk alongside this chasm isn't it".

Comment: If you want one oscillator to always be at a higher frequency than the other then you should separate the frequencies enough. How much requires some statistics calculations.

Comment: You specify a measurement period of one second. This involves **Allan Variance**...you might try reading how this applies to oscillator frequency:https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI1Neu3PrXAhVn54MKHSQ3Am8QFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rakon.com%2Fcomponent%2Fdocman%2Fdoc_download%2F291-variance-as-applied-to-crystal-oscillators%3FItemid%3D&usg=AOvVaw0x8pSsmD_yjLji_2_T1M33

Comment: I should say that the reason I am asking this question is to understand the symptoms while debugging a problem I am looking into, not because I want to make a design where I need to make this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources of frequency error in a crystal.

The first is the initial tolerance. This will be specified in the data sheet. Very cheap crystals may have been adjusted by the manufacturer to +/- 50ppm, more expensive ones to fractions of a ppm.

The next is temperature coefficient. Cheap crystals will vary by a a few ppm per degree C, expensive ovened ones by fractions of a ppm per degree.

The next is ageing. Over the course of months, and years, the frequency will slowly change. Aging is fastest when the crystal is driven at high power. Cheap ones ... you get the general idea now.

Finally we have phase noise. The frequency of a crystal will vary from uS to uS, mS to mS, and second to second, by small amounts, due to various mechanisms. Cheap ones ... and you know the rest.

If the initial tolerance difference of two crystals exceeds the peak sum of the variable terms, then the same crystal will always be faster than the other one. If it's less, then they will swap places as their frequencies vary.

The best way is to measure your two particular crystals against each other, and plot a distribution of the frequency difference, so you can determine the standard deviation. If the mean difference is more than 10 times the standard deviation, then you're quite likely to see the same one always faster. If the mean difference is less than a few times the standard deviation, then you're likely to see them switching places for which is fastest from time to time.

Comment: This does not answer the question! I know that I can do my own measurements, I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: It does answer the question. It tells you what to measure, and that they're not on the data sheet. The datasheet PPM does not tell the whole story for the specific question you were asking.